# Nunit - Test protected method default constructor missing exception

Tags: c#, exception, inheritance, nunit, protected

I'd like to test (with [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=home)) the following class, in particular the **protected** method `ProtectedMethod`.

```
public class Foo
{
    protected bool ProtectedMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

In order to access to the protected method I wrote a test class that inherit from `Foo` in this way:

```
[TestFixture]
internal class FooTestable : Foo
{
    [Test]
    public void ProtectedMethod_Test()
    {
        bool result = ProtectedMethod();
        Assert.That(result);
    }
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
FooTestable does not have a default constructor
```

What does it mean?

Is this the best way to test protected methods?

Comment: The error usually means that a class does not have a constructor that takes no arguments. Does FooTestable have a constructor that takes arguments? If so, you need to change it to FooTestable() : base("a", "b") providing defaults for the base class construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to test protected method is to create testable implementation of the class inheriting the base class `FooTestable` and TestClass `FooTests` and keep this classes separated.

```
public class FooTestable : Foo
{
    public new bool ProtectedMethod()
    {
        return base.ProtectedMethod();
    }

    public FooTestable () {}
}

[TestFixture]
public class FooTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ProtectedMethod_Test()
    {
        FooTestable fooInstance = new FooTestable();

        Assert.That(fooInstance.ProtectedMethod());
    }
}
```

> FooTestable does not have a default constructor

The error means that the base class `Foo` a has constructor with parameters and doesn't have the default constructor, so you need to add a constructor  to the child class and call base constructor from it using `base` keyword.

For example

```
    public FooTestable ():base(1,2,3)/*calling the base class constructor*/ {}
    public FooTestable (int a, int b, int c):base(a,b,c) {}
```